# converting hidden files in to normal files in linux

Tags: linux, file, hidden, visible

I have a directory, let's say its name is **direct** in which has multiple files whose names are `.xyz`, `.abc`, `.klm` and `.etk4` etc. Is there a way to make all those hidden files visible at the same time instead of one by one? I know this question has been asked before here but I did not get the answer. I hope somebody can explain it to me in a simple way since I am not much familiar with linux.

Comment: If their names are `file1`, `file2`, `file3` and `file4`, then they are not hidden files.

Comment: How are the files hidden, if their name does not start with a `.`?

Comment: sorry I forgot to put "dot"before name of the files in my questions.They are supposed to be like this **.file1**, **.file2**, **.file3** and **.file4**

Comment: What is wrong with e.g. `ls -a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for file in .[^.]*
do
    mv "${file}" "${file#.}"
done
```

`${var#prefix}` expands to the value of `$var` with the initial `prefix` removed.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for you reply.I must have clarified everything in my question. I edited it now. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use a more general wildcard. The important thing is to use a wildcard that doesn't match `.` and `..`, since those represent the current and parent directory, and you don't want to rename them.